# Is it normal for Apple push notifications to use the IRC protocol?

Tags: macos, wireshark, apple

Seeing traffic like this on my network and wondering if it’s normal to see IRC being used in macOS push notifications and if anyone has any idea what the apparently escaped code (based on all of the backslashes present) is and/or what it's doing.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is obviously not IRC traffic. This is just using port 57000 which just happen to be also used by dircproxy and that's why Wireshark is trying to interpret the traffic as IRC. And then this misunderstanding by Wireshark is taken as a fact by the OP, who wonders why IRC is used at all and why the traffic looks much different than expected from IRC. I propose to close the question since it is based on the wrong assumptions.

Comment: Or with more detail: port 57000 is a port in the usual range of [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) and thus quite likely to be used sometimes as the source port in a TCP connection. And that's exactly what is happening here. The destination port of the TCP connection is instead [5223 - used among other by apple push notification](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=5223).